# Graphics2D - Antialias a Nearest-Neighbor along pixel borders

Tags: java, swing, graphics, graphics2d, antialiasing

I have a (small) `BufferedImage` wich needs to be enlarged using nearest neighbor interpolation and then drawn to a `Graphics2D`. The Image has 1-bit alpha information and rendering it with antialiasing on and this code

```
AffineTransform oldT = g.getTransform();
Paint oldP = g.getPaint();
int w = img.getWidth(), h = img.getHeight();
g.transform(at);
g.setPaint(new TexturePaint(img, new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, w, h)));
g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
g.setPaint(oldP);
g.setTransform(oldT);
```

Where `img` is the`BufferedImage` to be rendered using `at` as an `AffineTransform`. The antialiasing activated by

```
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

produces good results, but only for the *border* of the entire image; looking very strange:

[image]

Notice the top border is actually the image border while the right is a transition from opaque to transparent pixel.

Is there a best practice to achieve the same antialiasing within the image as is applied to the border? Note that other interpolation methods than NearestNeighbor are unacceptable.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

The rendering shouldn't take too long since it is part of a `paintComponent` method, but preprocessing the `BufferedImage` is possible. The `AffineTransform` is (very) variable, though.

---

**EDIT**

I have achieved a small improvement by using a two-step method:

```
AffineTransform oldT = g.getTransform();
Paint oldP = g.getPaint();
int w = img.getWidth(), h = img.getHeight(), texw = (int) (w*oldT.getScaleX()), texh = (int) (h *  oldT.getScaleY());
BufferedImage tex = new BufferedImage(texw, texh, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D tg = tex.createGraphics();
tg.scale(oldT.getScaleX(), oldT.getScaleY());
tg.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
g.transform(at);
g.scale(1/oldT.getScaleX(), 1/oldT.getScaleY());
g.setPaint(new TexturePaint(tex, new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, texw, texh)));
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
g.fillRect(0, 0, texw, texh);
g.setPaint(oldP);
g.setTransform(oldT);
```

Resulting in this image:

[image]

This is still not perfect, though. I tried `VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC`, but this is just incredibly slow and essentially produces the same result. I hope there is a way the get the exact same antialiasing effect, since it is still irritating.

Comment: An http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would probably be helpful here - particularly, one including the original image, since according to one statement, it seems that the artifacts only appear **IN** the image, when it contains a transition from fully opaque to fully transparent pixels. (It might be bit tricky to solve this, but maybe someone would give it a try...)

Comment: @Marco13 The problem here is indepentent of the particular image and I have finally found a good-looking and performing solution. I will post this as a temporary answer if noone comes up with a better way. When I have the time, I might also make an MCVE but this is a fairly complicated one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly complicated solution with a lot of tweaking and testing put into provides a very good quality by rendering each pixel as a shape reading its color and transparency from the `BufferedImage`:

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Composite;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class VectorizedImage {
    private final BufferedImage img;

    public VectorizedImage(BufferedImage img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        Color oldC = g.getColor();
        Composite oldCo = g.getComposite();
        AlphaComposite comp = AlphaComposite.SrcOver;
        double lap = 1/Math.sqrt(g.getTransform().getDeterminant()); // This deals with inter-pixel borders letting the background shine through
        Path2D pixel = new Path2D.Double();
        pixel.moveTo(0, 0);
        pixel.lineTo(0, 1);
        pixel.lineTo(1, 1);
        pixel.lineTo(1, 0);
        pixel.lineTo(0, 0);
        pixel.transform(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(1+lap, 1+lap));
        for (int i = 0; i < img.getWidth(); i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < img.getHeight(); j++) {
                g.setColor(new Color(img.getRGB(i, j)));
                g.setComposite(comp.derive(img.getAlphaRaster().getSampleFloat(i, j, 0) / 255));
                g.fill(pixel.createTransformedShape(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(i, j)));
        }
        g.setColor(oldC);
        g.setComposite(oldCo);
    }
}
```

The result is this nicely rendered edge:
[image]